# In PHP, I'm getting an error message on line 2, which says Undefined Index ID-addmsg?

Tags: php

The code is working, however I still recieve undefined index with the Id "addmsg"

```
     <?php
     $addmsg=$_GET["addmsg"];
     if (isset($addmsg)) // If the user wants to add a Message
     { 
     ?>
```

This is the code for the textarea and the submit buttons:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <p>Post your Message:<br />
    <textarea name="msg" rows="10" cols="70" wrap></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="smtmsg" value="SUBMIT" /></p>
    </form>
```

Lastly, this code is to connect to the Mysql database

```
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ."?addmsg=1";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check isset before assigning the variable:

```
<?php

     if (isset($_GET["addmsg"])) // If the user wants to add a Message
     { 
          $addmsg=$_GET["addmsg"];
     }
?>
```

You use $_POST so the field msg would never be evaluated here. Either change the $_GET['addmsg'] to $_POST['msg'] or change the field msg to addmsg and change the form type to "get"

Answer (score 0):

There is no field named "addmsg" in your HTML. The only one you have is named "msg".

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting to `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`, so on your server side, there is no index `addmsg` in the `$_GET` superglobal.

You should change your form action to `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?addmsg=1";?>` as you have in the last line of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The message mean exactly what it says.  The is nothing set at `$_GET['addmsg']`.

In this case, you have two problems. Your form method is set to `post`.  You must therefore look for your value in `$_POST`

Second, you must actually have a field named `addmsg` in your form.  The field in your form is named `msg`.  So the value would be available as `$_POST['msg']`

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 errors:

First:

IF the method is "post", the variable is $_POST.

Second:

The textarea's name is "msg", then you have to do $_POST["msg"].

Of course, if methos="get", the variable is $_GET["msg"]